# Will jQuery ajaxStop() make recursive calls ? if so, how to stop it?

Tags: jquery

I'm showing `Ajax login form` for various user action in my portal, once successfully login I want to update some `div's` for that I'm using following code,

```
 $(document).ajaxStop(function(){

        $.get($(location).attr('href'),function(html){
        var $html = $(html);
        $('#topBar').html($html.find('#topBar'));
        $('#commentsForm').html($html.find('#commentsForm'));
        });
  });
```

Will above code leads to any recursive `Ajax` calls ? currently its working as expected but I want to know it clearly.

**Update:**

I kept `log` at end of the `ajaxStop` then it printing `log message` recursively then it shows clearly that above code making recursive calls.

Comment: How did you determine that it works as expected? Have you checked the Network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Answer (score 3):

I think this will cause recursion. After all the other AJAX calls complete, this handler will call. It will start a new AJAX call with `$.get()`, and when that completes it will trigger the handler, which will call `$.get()`, and so on.

To prevent this, you can do:

```
$.ajaxSetup( { global: false } );
```

to prevent global AJAX handlers from running. Or replace `$.get()` with the equivalent `$.ajax()` call, and use `global: false` in its options argument.

Comment: is there any alternative for this ? Thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

Yes: http://jsfiddle.net/GghtK/

`ajaxStop()` listens for all future ajax calls (you are creating an event listener to the `ajaxStop` event which jQuery fires after all outstanding ajax requests are completed) you are then creating a new ajax request from within the callback which will of course in return fire the `ajaxStop` event.